# Obtaining the name of the index locked for a Lock:Acquired trace event

Tags: sql-server, locking, trace

I'm capturing [Lock:Acquired](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189897.aspx) trace events uing SQL Server Profiler and I would like to be able to identify the name of the index that the lock applies to for KEY type locks.

I can do this for OBJECT lock types (by executing the following query using the value from the `ObjectID` column in the trace):

```
SELECT OBJECT_ID( /* my object id */ )
```

However for KEY lock types the `ObjectID` column is empty, and the `ObjectID2` column contains a `bigint` value, which is too large to work using the above query.

How can I find what index a KEY lock applies to from my trace?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this answer from a very intelligent SQL Server MVP

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/33177368/what-is-the-objectid2-column-for-locks-acquired-referring-to.aspx

If you captured your lock trace, and while the transaction is open, in Query Windows enter this

```
select * from sys.dm_tran_locks
exec sp_lock
```

You will see various information that correlate mostly to the TextData column in the trace. That appears to be a physical page/location within that is being locked - no locks are placed on indexes per-se, locks are mostly for KEY (record) or PAGE.